# Using LIKE in a SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm making a search box to search the name of users in my database. The database has a firstname and lastname field. I want to search these fields to find users who match the query. So I came up with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE (firstname + ' ' + lastname) LIKE ('%' + @query + '%')
```

It works but I'm not sure if thats the best way to do it. Especially as the database gets bigger. Is there a better solution or will this suffice?

Comment: Are you sure you need `LIKE`? Seems that this will do what you need ... `SELECT * FROM user WHERE (firstname+' '+lastname) = @query` ... I suppose it depends on if your @query is likely to be exact

Comment: You may be [okay with `LIKE`](http://sqlserverperformance.idera.com/tsql-optimization/replace-poorly-performing-substring-function-sql-server-statement/) but if you're worried you can use SQL Management Studio and check the execution plan to confirm performance.

Comment: You might want `where firstname like '%' + @query + '%' or lastname like '%' + @query + '%'`. That way a match on part of either the first or last name will be included in the result set.

Comment: Well if someone enter 'James h' for example that wouldn't work. Forgot to mention it has to match partial text too :(

Comment: What you have can't use an index, because of two reasons: The combination of the two columns, and the use of the wildcard on the left side of a `LIKE`.  Full Text Search would be a better idea.

Comment: It's not necessarily a better way, but you could have a non-persisted computed column called fullname that represents firstname + ' ' + lastname. I'd only do this if you find you are combining these fields often as it is useful, and will make your queries a little nicer to read.

Comment: @user92546 that one doesn't work either with the example above 'james h' to match James Hay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at SQL server's Full Text Indexing capabilities: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

It may be a bit of refactoring but it's much more efficient to search an index as opposed to row by row.

If you outgrow that, you can always consider something like Lucene.Net. It has much more flexibility in terms of query operators.  It's a completely separate indexing and query engine, so it would likely take a fair bit of refactoring.  Just something to consider.

Comment: Whoa full text search looks awesome, will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

add a Computed Columns in db: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx
and then query against that column

Answer (score 0):

to get all possible search users best way is to compare it individually for getting user by inserted search text but as it wont include full name in search. So to include full name we are considering full name also by taking a space in between.

```
(First_Name LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%') OR (Last_Name LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%') OR (First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%')
```

Comment: But wont this just decrease performance while giving the same result?